# dhtmlxscheduler usage with ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use dhtmlxscheduler within an ASP.NET MVC 5 application by following the guide available at http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/how_to_start.html but not having much joy. I have added v4.1.1 scripts and css to my project via NuGet.

I have created a new project and created a new view without layout, the controller action simply serves the view. Below is the HTML in my view but the page renders totally blank, what am I doing wrong? Also, how would I get this to work with a view that uses a layout?

I am aware there is a dhtmlxscheduler .NET version available but this requires a license.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>How to start</title>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dhtmlxscheduler/dhtmlxscheduler.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dhtmlxscheduler/dhtmlxscheduler.css")" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
<script>
    scheduler.init("scheduler_here", new Date(), "month");
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
                <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" id="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" id="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" id="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue/solution was already in the FAQ http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/faq.html#schedulerisntrenderedcorrectly

My containing div did not have a height set.